# For Loop Variables within Loops

Tags: apex, soql

I'm still learning Apex, but essentially working on a scheduled class that aggregates different related (not necessarily child) objects to an account and calculates a score based on averages and such.

I essentially set this up as one larger for-loop for the accounts, with nested for-loops and if statements therein, on my debug logs each time my :acct.id is referenced it shows as tempvar1, and 0 records queried, this is leading me to receive 'Divide by 0' errors when running.

Basically it starts like this...

```
for(Account acct : CHA_Master_Acct_List){

//Account Level Items

    integer E2ECertified = 0;
    IF(acct.End_to_End_Certified__c == TRUE){
        E2ECertified = 3;
    }
    system.debug('E2E Certified: ' + E2ECertified);

    integer ClientDirect = 0;
    IF(acct.Partnership_Type__c == 'Client'){
        ClientDirect = 5;
    }

    system.debug('Client Direct: ' + ClientDirect);

    list<Partner> PartnerList = new list<Partner>();
    PartnerList = [SELECT Id, AccountFromId, Role FROM Partner WHERE AccountFromId = :acct.Id AND Role = 'Agency'];
    system.debug(PartnerList);

    boolean HasPartner = FALSE;

    IF(PartnerList.size() > 0){
        HasPartner = TRUE;
    }

    system.debug(HasPartner);
```

Comment: Umm...what is your question? Aside from the fact that you have a query in a for loop, which you should ***never do***, it's hard to grasp much based on what you have posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

> this is leading me to receive 'Divide by 0' errors when running.

I don't see any division anywhere in the code you pasted. If this is the issue you are facing please post the code that does the division.

You are querying Partner in a FOR LOOP which will hit the governor limits if you ever process more than 100 records.  You should move the query outside of the for loop to prevent this.  You can use a map to get the Partner records related to your accounts.

```
Map<Id, List<Partner>> accountPartnerMap = new Map<Id, List<Partner>>();
for(Partner p : [SELECT Id, AccountFromId, Role FROM Partner WHERE AccountFromId IN :CHA_Master_Acct_List AND Role = 'Agency']){

    if( !accountPartnerMap.containsKey(p.AccountFromId) ){
        accountPartnerMap.put(p.AccountFromId, new List<Parnter>());
    }
    accountParnterMap.get(p.AccountFromId).add(p);
}
```

Then in your for loop you can get your partner records by using the Account Id;

```
List<Partner> partners = accountPartnerMap.get(acct.Id);
HasPartner = !partners.isEmpty();
```

---

On a side note this bit of code

```
IF(acct.End_to_End_Certified__c == TRUE)
```

is basically saying `IF( TRUE == TRUE)` which is redundant you could easily make your code

```
integer E2ECertified = 0;
IF(acct.End_to_End_Certified__c){
    E2ECertified = 3;
}
```

Also this bit of code here

```
IF(acct.Partnership_Type__c == 'Client'){
    ClientDirect = 5;
}
```

It would be a good practice to make `'Client'` a constant and declare it at the top of the class

```
private static final CLIENT = 'Client'
```

and then do the check like so

```
IF( CLIENT.equals(acct.Partnership_Type__c) ){
    ClientDirect = 5;
}
```

This way you can re-use CLIENT in multiple locations, and it'll be easier to locate and change later.

Answer (score 0):

Since the records in question already have a relationship to the Account (they don't have to be child relationships), a cleaner way to query would be to use relationship references in a single SOQL query from the Account, then use for loops on the one result:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name, 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts), 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Custom_Field_Relationship_Name__r) 
FROM Account];

for (Account acc : accs) {
  for(Contact ct : acc.Contacts){
    // process contact records
  }
  if(!acc.Custom_Field_Relationship_Name__r.isEmpty()) {
    // flag something as true
  }
  for(Custom_Object__c co : acc.Custom_Field_Relationship_Name__r){
    // process custom object records
  }
}
```